# Best Duration type in Java or .Net

Tags: java, .net

I have seen way to many places where a method takes a long or an int to represent durations in either nanoseconds, milliseconds (most common), seconds and even days. This is a good place to look for errors, too.

The problem is also quite complex once you realize that you can mean for the duration to be a certain number of seconds, or an interval that fits the human perception of time better, so that a duration of 24 hours is always going to be the next day at the same "wall-clock" time. Or that a year is either 365 or 366 days depending on the date, so that a year from 28th of February is always going to be the 28th of February.

Why is there no distinct type to represent this? I have found none in either Java or .net

Comment: What would you call an object representing an absolute number of milliseconds and an object representing the "human-friendly" perception of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java, take a look at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) (an intuitive and consistent date/time library) and its [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) classes. `DateTime` objects can handle addition and manipulation via these objects.

(answer changed to reflect the comments below re. the Period class)

Comment: Joda's Duration class is just a wrapper around a ms value and is not able to represent longer durations like "one day" correctly.

Comment: True - but Joda provides both the `Duration`  and `Period` classes to represent similar concepts.  The latter isn't an exact number of milliseconds but can be "one day" or "one month", with their exact actual duration dependent on the start of the interval they're applied to.

Comment: ...which actually is exactly what the OP was asking for if I understand his requirements correctly - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html

Comment: That does look a lot more relevant. I've edited to highlight the above.

Answer (score 8):

In .Net you can use the [TimeSpan structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to represent a length of time.

Comment: Many programmers don't know this structure exists because they don't see it represented in the native C# or VB.NET data types - voted you up - encouraging more people to do the same so this often missed data type is made well known.

Comment: Of course, if you subtract or add dates in .NET, you get a TimeSpan back.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't quite meet what the original question was asking about.  For example, there's no `TimeSpan.FromYears(int)` method.  Internally it's measured as a 64-bit unsigned integer containing the number of milliseconds since some epoch.  There's no abstract concept of a month/year that holds across all cases, irrespective of variable month lengths and leap-years.  I don't think such a type exists in the .NET BCL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy problem. Maybe [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/) would be a useful library for you. It has a Duration class that can do what you are asking for.